# Deleting elements from a dynamic array in C

Tags: c

So I am trying to make an app which will make an array of 26 values and pick random numbers to fill it, after that I have to find duplicates and  delete it.
This is what I have done until now, the problem which I really don't understand is why it works for a size of 10 but not for any value bigger than 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int remove_element(int** array, int sizeOfArray, int indexToRemove)
{
    int i;

    int* temp = malloc((sizeOfArray - 1) * sizeof(int));

    memmove(
            temp,
            *array,
            (indexToRemove+1)*sizeof(int));

    memmove(
            temp+indexToRemove,
            (*array)+(indexToRemove+1),
            (sizeOfArray - indexToRemove)*sizeof(int));

    free (*array);
    *array = temp;
    return 0;

}

int findDuplicate(int* array, int sizeOfArray){
    int i, j;


    for( j = 0 ; j < sizeOfArray ; j++ ) {
        for(i = 0; i < sizeOfArray; i++){
            if(array[i] == array[j] && i != j){
                    return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
   time_t t;
   srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    int arraySize = 11;
    int* test = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int*));
    int i, indexToRemove = 0;

   for( i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++ ) {
      test[i] = ((rand() % (91 + 1 - 65)) + 65);
   }

    for( i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++){
        printf("%d, ", test[i]);
    }

    printf("\n============================================\n");

    for (i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++){
        indexToRemove = findDuplicate(test,arraySize);

        if ( indexToRemove != 0){
            remove_element(&test, arraySize, indexToRemove);
            arraySize = arraySize - 1;  
        }   
    }

    for( i = 0 ; i < arraySize ; i++){
        printf("%d, ", test[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(indexToRemove+1)` should just be `indexToRemove` in the first `memmove()`

Comment: `(sizeOfArray - indexToRemove)` should be `(sizeOfArray - indexToRemove - 1)`

Comment: Why don't you check if the number is already in the array before inserting it? And then at the end once realloc the array to the size it's filled.

Comment: `sizeof(int*)` should be `sizeof(int)`

Comment: Baring that swap the indexToRemove with the last element and realloc instead of copying all the numbers every time. You can even just keep track of how many numbers to remove and realloc once at the end.

Comment: Thanks Barmar don t know how i messed that , Thanks

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow i will try that too thanks